# Magento 2 using Redis Cluster and occur error 500 when start website

Tags: magento2, configuration, redis

My company platform team have deployed redis cluster on 3 nodes (10.193.1.1, 10.193.1.2,10.193.1.3) for port 6379.

I have update the env.php to redis as following
......
....
array (
'backend'=> 'Cm_cache_backend_Redis',
'backend_options' =>
array (
'server' => '10.193.1.1',
'port'=>'6379',
......),
array (
'server' => '10.193.1.2',
'port'=>'6379',
......),
array (
'server' => '10.193.1.3',
'port'=>'6379',
......),

Then it show error on /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log
CredisException: ERR select is not allowed in cluster mode
The website could not open ERROR 500

Any suggestion?

Comment: any solution for this? facing same error